# Background image not displaying in ie 9

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

One of my background images isn't display in ie 9, the one called 'djembe-drums' [here](http://djembefola.com/shop/index.php).

It's working in FF and other browsers....Can anyone see what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the class `djembecategory` on that element instead of `djembeCategory`.

There is a bug in many versions/modes of IE where CSS selectors are case-sensitive.